# Classificação morfológica das palavras

Tags: morfologia

Qual a classificação morfológica das frases abaixo? Realizei a divisão, mas não tenho certeza.

**É dever cristão praticar o bem.**

```
É dever = Locução Verbal.
Praticar = Verbo.
o = artigo.
bem = substantivo.
```

**A Inglaterra é responsável por sua economia.**

```
A = Artigo.
Inglaterra = Substantivo.
é = Verbo.
responsável = Adjetivo.
por = Preposição.
sua = Pronome.
Economia = Substantivo.
```

Comment: morfologia? Ramo da lingüística que estuda a estrutura interna das palavras? Você quer dizer a função da palavra na frase? as classes gramaticais?

Comment: A função das palavras .

Comment: Eis as que conheço: substantivo, verbo, adjetivo, pronome, artigo, numeral, preposição, conjunção, interjeição e advérbio. uma locução verbal é uma estrutura. Porque se compõe de um verbo (é) e um substantivo (dever).

Answer (score 1):

Do ponto de vista morfológico ([taxonómico](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/taxinomia)) e não sintático, a sua categorização parece correta.

> A morfologia é parte da gramática que estuda as **classes** e as formas das palavras, os seus paradigmas de flexão e os processos de formação de novos vocábulos

Acrescentaria apenas que `sua` é um pronome possessivo e que de acordo com [esta fonte](https://www.todamateria.com.br/classes-de-palavras/), uma locução verbal não é uma classe de palavras.

Comment: "é dever" não são dois verbos. "é" vem do verbo ser e "dever" é uma obrigação, ou seja,um substantivo.

Comment: @Lambie, corrigido!

Comment: Acho que morfologia não é a palavra correta aqui. :)

Comment: @Lambie, porquê? A Infopédia [refere](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/morfologia) que estuda a classe das palavras.

Comment: @Lambie a [wikipédia confirma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfologia_(lingu%C3%ADstica)): _Na morfologia, há classes de palavras variáveis (substantivos, adjetivos, verbos, pronomes, numerais e artigos) e invariáveis (advérbios, conjunções, interjeições e preposições_

Comment: @Lambie claro que tecnicamente poderíamos mencionar, tal como na Biologia, que a ciência que estuda as classes é a **Taxonomia** ;) Mas não encontrei fontes para tal na Linguística!

Comment: Wikipedia diz: A morfologia ("morf(o)-" e "-logia" são provenientes do grego transliterado morphe que significa "forma" e logía que significa "estudo"[1]) trata de um modo geral do estudo da estrutura e formação das palavras.[2][3][4] Ao estudar morfologia, estudamos a formação de palavras através de elementos morfológicos (ou mórficos),[5] que são as unidades que formam uma palavra. Alguns elementos morfológicos são: radical, tema, vogal temática, vogal ou consoante de ligação, afixo, desinência (nominal ou verbal). O que você está preguntando não é "morfologia" em si.

Comment: @Lambie tu estás a ir ao étimo da palavra, mas como não existe *[taxonomia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/taxinomia)* na linguística (que eu saiba), todas as fontes que li referem que é a morfologia que estuda as classes das palavras. Em qualquer caso inquiri noutra [fonte](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-branch-of-linguistics-that-studies-the-classes-of-words).

Comment: Me discupla, mas a morfologia tem a ver com a forma das palavras. Não os elementos (categorias) da gramática. Isso fica claro demais no Wikipedia. Classes de palavras variavéis, sim. Por exemplo: eu ficou, eles ficam. ou/am fazem parte da morfologia. Um verbo em si não.

Comment: @Lambie a WP diz claramente que "na morfologia, há classes de palavras variáveis (substantivos, adjetivos, verbos, pronomes, numerais e artigos) e invariáveis (advérbios, conjunções, interjeições e preposições)"

Comment: Pois é. Exatamente. "***A peculiaridade da morfologia é estudar as palavras olhando para elas isoladamente e não dentro da sua participação na frase ou período***." https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/

Comment: Conforme o Dicionário de linguística e fonética, de D. Crystal, a morfologia é o "ramo da gramática que estuda a estrutura ou as formas das palavras,
principalmente por meio de construções com morfemas". Ela não trata apenas da classificação óbvia de palavras num dado sistema linguístico.